# Visual Studio Code não funciona em Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

Estou tentando usar o Visual Studio Code no Ubuntu 16.04 x64, mas não obtive sucesso.

Tentei instalar via pacote .deb e todo o procedimento aparentemente ocorreu bem. Mas ao tentar abrir o programa já instalado, a tela fica da seguinte maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Baixei então o arquivo .zip, extrai tudo e tentei executar o programa de lá, mas também obtive o mesmo resultado.

Além dessas duas tentativas, recorri ao `ubuntu-make`, mas mais uma vez obtive o mesmo resultado.

Em minhas pesquisas não encontrei nada que pudesse me ajudar a sair dessa tela.

Afinal, como posso usar o Visual Studio Code em meu Linux?

Comment: Experimenta abrir o programa com sudo a ver se funciona.

Comment: Infelizmente acontece a mesma coisa...

Comment: Verificou se tem algum pacote faltando? Esta parecendo que tem algum problema ou esta faltando algo na biblioteca gráfica

Comment: Ainda sou iniciante em Linux (estou tentando expandir horizontes, rsrsrs...), mas pelo que pude ver via pacote .deb não era pra faltar nada, correto?
A única coisa estranha que percebi foi um aviso conforme nessa imagem: http://i.imgur.com/LnMQuQM.png

Comment: Estou desconfiado que possa ser algo no SO, pois o [Atom](https://atom.io/) também ficou da mesma forma.

Comment: Como fica o Chromium nesse seu Ubuntu? O computador é virtual ou físico?

Comment: Estou usando no Virtual Box, vou testar o Chromium...

Comment: Tenta instalar pelo gerenciador de aplicações.